# panda dataframe count by month but break down by value

Tags: python, pandas

my db has the following format:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQt5u.png)

I'm trying to get a count of each region grouped by month and i've tried different methods but still can't figure it out. I keep getting a total count for each month but can't get it to break down by region by month

the last method I tried was set_index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

ax['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ax['date'])
ax = report[['date','region']].copy()
ax['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(ax['date']).month
ax = ax.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
ax
```

but this one returns a total count of reoccurences for each region.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoQ8F.png)

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: please provide sample data in text format, not images :)

Comment: `df.groupby(['month', 'region'])['region'].count()`

Comment: @Chris thank you!! that is exactly what I needed